# FFMPEG split mp3 and add metatag

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, metadata, mp3

I have a 2 hour mp3 that I automatically split with python3 and ffmpeg into many mp3 files. I would also like to add metadata to mp3 files, in order to have title, artist, year and album.

In a csv file I have the cutting times and the name of the mp3 file, but I can't add meta data. The function I use is this:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel panic -i 1.mp3 -ss 02:29:11 -to 02:34:43 -c copy -metadata 'title=My Title', 'artist=ME', 'date=2023' temp/myfile1.mp3
```

Not work, It only works if I set the title only. Can you help me, please?
Thank you,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`-metadata` can only be used for setting 1 key=value pair at a time, you need to use this flag multiple times, once for each key=value pair, like this

```
-metadata title="My Title" -metadata artist="ME" -metadata date="2023" -metadata album="My Album"
```